# Looking for solubility kinetics of zinc chloride hydroxide monohydrate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, kinetics, solubility, solutions, reference-request

$\ce{Zn5(OH)8Cl2.H2O}$ is a crystalline solid insoluble in water. Often used as nutritional supplement. Preparation and chemistry of [zinc chloride hydroxide monohydrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_chloride_hydroxide_monohydrate) is known. I am looking for some additional data such as solubility or solubility kinetics basically in anything. I wasn't able to find any valid data.

Comment: Guess it would dissolve in any strong acid or alkali.

Comment: There's 500 pages report in German by the *Gesellschaft für Anlagen- und Reaktorsicherheit (GRS)* titled  [Entwicklung eines thermodynamischen Modells für Zink, Blei und Cadmium in salinaren Lösungen](http://www.grs.de/sites/default/files/pdf/GRS-219.pdf). Around page 283, there a bit on Simonkolleite.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Thank you a lot! I will take look at it.